# Python imaplib documentation

Tags: python, imap, imaplib, code-documentation

I'm looking into the python `imaplib` library and starting testing things. I looked in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) and
read that `get_payload()` is deprecated and you have to use `get_body()`.
When I look at my object with `dir()` I have `get_payload()` but not `get_body()`. (I use python 3.9.5.)

Why does the documentation not match the object I get? Is there a good and up-to date introduction to `imaplib`?

Comment: If you want to work with IMAP: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Comment: Not a tutorial, but quite nicely written. Thanks.